# Disable a function for a specific mob

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a map with mobs. I have piglin on a magma cube. When the cube jumps the eagle sitting on it takes damage due to the fact that it passes through the texture. Is it possible to use the command to disable this function on a specific sitting mob?

I'm using Minecraft 1.19.2.

Comment: Do you want to prevent the eagle from suffocating, or prevent the magma cube from jumping?

Comment: I want the magma cube to jump and the piglin will not take damage when passing through the blocks

Answer (score 0):

You can put the piglin and the magma cube on a team with friendly fire disabled.

Create a team:

```
/team add noDamage
```

Disable friendly fire for the team:

```
/team modify noDamage friendlyFire false
```

Add the piglin and magma cube to the team:

```
/team join noDamage @e[type=piglin,limit=1,sort=nearest]
/team join noDamage @e[type=magma_cube,limit=1,sort=nearest]
```

The magma cube will no longer be able to damage the piglin.